# Unable to understand a Docker-compose service property

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new to docker, and stumbled upon a docker-compose file. I get the gist of all other properties but I have no idea what below line is doing:

> volumes:
>         - ./data:/data/db

Can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

multiple volumes can be attached to your container ... each are defined as a pair

```
volumes:
- /parent/host/path01:/inside/container/path_one    
- /parent/host/path02:/inside/container/path_another
```

of each pair the left side is a pre-existing volume reachable on host before container is created ... right side is what the freshly launched container views that left side as from inside the container

in your example, in same dir where you launch docker-compose from, there evidently exists a dir called data ... using ./data will reach it using a relative path ... the right side /data/db  is what the code in your container calls that same dir

```
/full/path/to/reach/data:/data/db
```

is using the absolute path to reach that same ./data dir which lives on the parent host which docker-compose is executed on

This volume mapping allows permanent storage on parent host to become visible (read/writable) to the container ... since the container filesystem is ephemeral and so goes away when container exits this volume mapping gives the container access to permanent storage for specified paths which must appear in your yaml file ... especially important for database containers like mongo ... all files used in your container not mapped in the volumes yaml disappear once the container exists

Here is a typical yaml snippet for mongo where it gains access to permanent storage on parent host

```
  loudmongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: loud_mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
     - 127.0.0.1:27017:27017
    volumes:
     - /cryptdata7/var/data/db:/data/db
```

Comment: Got it. But is this mapping really important?

Comment: @KumarSwapnil  both left and right sides can be identical, it just accommodates having them different if need be ... is that what you are asking ?

Comment: Do we need to define volumes property if we are using official mongo image.?

Comment: @KumarSwapnil yes if you want your mongo to get persisted and reusable on subsequent launches

Answer (score 1):

The dash symbol is probably what is throwing you off, because it is poorly formatted YAML syntax for a [YAML list element](https://github.com/Animosity/CraftIRC/wiki/Complete-idiot's-introduction-to-yaml#lists).

The volume syntax after the dash is just following the so-called ["short" syntax for a host-to-container bind-mounted volume mapping](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#short-syntax-3).

Comment: thanks. One more thing, what would happen if we do not map host directory to container.(  I mean simply ./data). And, is it necessary for persisting the data .

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you mean you will omit `./data` or do you mean you will omit `/data/db`? When you say you need to 'persist the data' what do you mean? Do you want it to be available on the host OS outside of any container? Or do you want it to persist by virtue of remaining inside the container for as long as the lifetime of the container (not just the runtime of the container, but the lifetime until the container is removed)?

Comment: I will omit ./data. persisting data means, I am using mongo image and the data should not be lost if the container is shut down and restarts again.

Comment: If you only pass a single path format of the volume mount, then it says to Docker Compose, "please secretly create a Docker volume, and make this path the mount point of the secret volume when I am running this container." So if you set it to, say, `/home/example`, then *inside* the container, there will be a `/home/example` path, and *while the container is running* that path will be a mount point of a dynamically created volume. For example, you could inspect it in `/var/lib/docker/volumes` and use `docker inspect` to get the generated mount name (it's like a long hash).

Comment: The big downside of this single-path approach is that the secret Docker volume is destroyed each time the container is removed, and whole new secret volume would be created each time you re-launch it. So it would not be useful for persisting data to the host OS unless you separately had scripts which were copying data out of the secret volume path during the container's lifetime.

Comment: Instead, you can use a [named volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/), so that the volume persists and can be re-mounted to any containers that need to access the data or a [bind-mounted volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/bind-mounts/) so that mutations of the mounted directory are also mutations within the host OS. There is also a [tmpfs option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/tmpfs/) which only persists in the host OS memory (it is not written to disk) and is removed when the container exits, to save things without committing to disk.